# How to grasp the concept of Binary Search recursion, with the example given in Java ?

Tags: java, recursion

Lately, I realized that I don't get the recursion as much as I thought so. That's why I'm trying to find as many examples as possible to figure it out, but I got caught very fast.

It's simple Binary Search code that works, yet I have very hard time understanding the recursion part. Especially because I don't see how anything changes with each further step. If at any point there was +1 or -1 given to any of variables, I might get it, but here variables are passed naturally, without any changes.

```
public class BinarySearchRecursion {
    public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int value, int start, int end) {
        if ((end - start) <= 1) {
            if (array[start] == value)
                return start;
            if (array[end] == value)
                return end;
            return -1;
        }

        int midPoint = (start + end) / 2;
        if (array[midPoint] > value) {
            return binarySearch(array, value, 0, midPoint);
        } else {
            return binarySearch(array, value, midPoint, end);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = { 4, 9, 10 };
        System.out.println(binarySearch(a, 10, 0, a.length - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would consider this a change: `int midPoint = (start + end) / 2;`

Comment: Code works just fine, but I don't understand the recursion. It's not my code

Comment: I know that the code works (with the exception of the problem pointed out by @Aasmund Eldhuset). You said "I don't see how anything changes with each further step" and "variables are passed (...) without any changes" so I pointed you to the line where a (/ the essential) variable change occurs.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Still don't understand. Where exactly does start or end change their values ?

Comment: I think @Aasmund has given a pretty good explanation. Every time you call `binarySearch(...)` and pass it some variables, a **new** function is started with its **own** variables `array`, `value`, `start` and `end` which are set to whatever was passed during the function call. These variables are put on the stack and every time the currently running function finishes, its variables are removed from the stack again. So even though they have the same name, they are completely different variables that the ones in the last `binarySearch` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misled by thinking that the parameter called `start` is the same variable throughout the different recursive calls - but this is *not* the case (and similarly for `end`). There is *no* direct connection between the value of a particular parameter in different recursive calls, even though it's got the same name. Instead, the parameter values are passed *by position*: when you call `binarySearch`, whatever expression you write in the third parameter position will become the value of `start` in the new call.

So if `array[midPoint] > value` is true, you'll call `binarySearch(array, value, 0, midPoint)`, which is actually a bug - it's supposed to be `binarySearch(array, value, start, midPoint)`. This means that in the new call, the value of `start` will be the same as in this call, but the value of `end` will be the value that this call computed for `midPoint`. Otherwise, you'll call `binarySearch(array, value, midPoint, end)`, so that in the new call, the value of `start` will be `midPoint`, and the value of `end` will be the same as in this call.

(This goes for all methods, not just recursive ones. Also, note that `array` and `value` *do* keep their values throughout the recursive calls, but that's because you "pass them to themselves" in the first and second parameter position.)